# how to rename the current volume group

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm, volume

we have redhat linux 7.2 version

how to replace the volume group from:

```
/dev/mapper/rh7-home   36G   33M   26G   1% /home
```

to:

```
/dev/mapper/rh7-var   36G   33M   26G   1% /var
```

Comment: You are asking how to rename `LV (Logical Volume)` since `rh7-home` is a logical volume. Show the output of `lvdisplay`

Comment: it's more likely here that "rh7" is the VG name and "home" & "var" are the LV names.  Since you showed new LV names, but are asking (title & body) about VG names, which is it?

Comment: And are you really getting rid of the /home partition in order to make it be /var ?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is to rename the Logical Volume. You can do it by using the lvrename command

```
lvrename /dev/rh7/home /dev/rh7/var
```